# Why is the CryptoKitties contract balance not the same as their revenue?

Tags: cryptokitties

I am doing research about the `CryptoKitties` game. I see that its revenue is about 12M USD. But when I visit the [CryptoKitties Smart Contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d) I see that the revenue is about 220k USD only. 
[image]

I think I have missed some points here but can you please explain to me why the contract balance is not the same as the revenue?

Thanks

Comment: This isn't revenue, the 220k is the current value that's in the contract.

Comment: @OrryVandermeulen But I think this value should be asymptotic with revenue. Because CryptoKitties revenue mostly because buying cat on blockchain. 200k USD is the big difference with 12M USD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the `withdrawBalance()` function inside the cryptoKitties contract you'll notice that the developers are able to withdraw "their cut" from the contract. This means every time the developers take their cut the amount will be subtracted from the contract Balance.

Revenue is the total amount of ether that has passed the contract (which means the ether still is inside the contract or it has been withdrawn.) That's why revenue and contract balance aren't the same.

Comment: wow. that makes sense :D I have one additional question. Can the owner withdrawn by using traditional way: send money from account A to account B. (without using smart contract function) ? If yes, will it remove from total balance ?

Comment: thanks for honest reply :D Can you make a question about this topic please. Because I think you understand better than me so your question will be clearer :D After you done, can you notice to me so I can follow that question. Thanks so much.